# DatePart indicates calendar week 53 for 30.12.2019

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA code gives the wrong calendar week for the date: 30.12.2019.

```
DatePart("ww", "30.12.2019", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) ' ->Output 53

DatePart("ww", "31.12.2019", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) ' ->Output 1
DatePart("ww", "29.12.2019", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) ' ->Output 52
```

Quick look at the right calendar https://www.kalender-365.eu/kalender-2019.html

It must be `1` not 53.

---

More tests:

```
DatePart("w", "30.12.2019", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) ' -> Output 1, means Sunday.
```

But `30.12.2019` is Monday.

```
DatePart("w", "31.12.2019", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) ' -> Output 2, means Monday
```

But `31.12.2019` is Tuesday.

Comment: The weekdays are correct since you use vbMonday, Monday equals 1, Tuesday 2, ... Sunday 7.
Don't know about the weeks though...

Comment: Ok, thanks for this hint. But ``DatePart("ww", "29.12.2019", 1, vbFirstFourDays) ' -> 53`` crazy.

Comment: You confuse the weekdays with the visual-Basic-constants. The constants vbMonday, vbSunday... only determine what week-Format DatePart uses and do not correlate with the integer-representation of the weekdays. You use 1 as third parameter here which is the same as vbSunday, therefore the 29th is already in the next week.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But the 29th is not in CW 53 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a strange bug. If you use the Excel-Function `WeekNum` with "21" as 2nd parameter (available in Excel 2010), the week for the 30.12.2019 is okay (=1). Starting from Excel 2013, there is also a function `IsoWeekNum`. If you need the week number in VBA, you can use `WorksheetFunction.WeekNum`

Comment: Ok, looks good. But can you explain to me what the second parameter "21" makes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff836525.aspx  ( 1 or 2 are possible )

Comment: No clue how Microsoft defined the numbers for the 2nd parameter, but its shown [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKNUM-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340). 21 is for ISO-weeknumbers.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and this link.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with your parameters. Try with the vbFirstJan1 on the last parameter.

Comment: Not really. The parameter means the ISO-Format of calendar week definition. The first week in year must have 4 days or more of January.
You can take a look at the calendar (link in my question) 30.12.2019 is Monday, 31.12.2019 is Tuesday. And this both days in calendar week 1.

Comment: 29 -> sunday last day of 52week ; 30-> first day of 53week; 1-> first day of 1st week (my guess is because of your parameter is setting this). But I agree, it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is a bug. 
I also calculated this specific date with Excel function WeekNum() using 21 as parameter. 
Everything is fine for all days (I tested Jan 01 2010 to Jan 7 2031).

But VBA produces this strange error only with "Dec 30 2019".
I used the function:

```
bWeek = Format(dDate, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
```

All calculations are correct with this function - excepted "Dec 30 2019". 
"Dec 29 2019" and "Dec 31 2019" were calculated correctly (results = 52 and 01).

Seems to me that there is bug in VBA.

Solution (because it is only this one date): I check "dDate" by if-clause and set weeknum by myself.

```
    If CDate(Day(dDate) & "." & Month(dDate) & "." & Year(dDate)) = CDate("30.12.2019") Then
        bWeek = 1 
        Exit Function 
    End If
```

Further explanation: I used Day(), Month() and Year() within CDate () because otherwise dates with timestamp will not work, to example "30.12.2019 0:00" is not equal to "31.12.2019"

Answer (score 0):

In addition:

From my point of view all hints above are not helpful.
There was no Layer8 error using VBA function.
Using vbFirstJan1 makes no sense, because results are totally different and not ISO conform.

Comment: Therefore, since all the answers dont make sense, what is the answer that will make sense? I failed to see that.